# Is there a quick way to see all of your (recent) posts in the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, posts

What is the algorithm used to determine whether your own posts are shown in the feed? I see mine sometimes just after posting, but there should be a quick way of displaying all recently active posts that I have contributed to, for all Stack Exchange sites.

Is there such a way?

Answer (score 2):

Open the "hamburger" menu and select your name to view your profile.

[image: "hamburger" menu icon]

Scroll down below the sites listed to the section labeled "Your recent activity". There you'll see your recent badges, comments, answers, and questions.

Comment: I don't think you even need open the hamburger menu; I think just tapping your user pic is enough (+1)